# update_or_create in my django rest framework api work wrong

Tags: python, django, database, api, django-rest-framework

[My problem in GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEVPj.gif)

Instead of updating the user's rating DRF creating new.
Maybe i made a mistake in serializer?
I wrote documentation but i dont kwon where i wrong.

My code:

**views.py:**

```
class CreateReviewView(APIView):
   
    def post(self, request):
        review = CreateReviewSerializer(data= request.data)
        if review.is_valid():
            review.save()
        return Response(status=201)

class CreateRatingView(APIView):
    def get_user(self, request):
        user= request.user
        if user =="AnonymousUser":
            return "noname in CreateRaringView"
        return user

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = CreateRatingSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            serializer.save(user=self.get_user(request))
            return Response(status=201)
        else:
            return Response(status=400)
```

**serializers.py:**

```
    class Meta:
        model = Rating
        fields = ('star','movie')

    def new(self,validated_data):
        
        rating = Rating.objects.update_or_create(
            
        user= validated_data.get('user',None),
        movie= validated_data.get('movie',None),
        defaults={'start': validated_data.get("star")}
        )
        return rating
```

**models.py:**

```
class Rating(models.Model):
    """Рейтинг"""
    
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="Пользователь",related_name='user')
    star = models.ForeignKey(RatingStar, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Звезда",related_name="star")
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Фильм",related_name="movie")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.star} - {self.movie}"

    class Meta:
        #unique_together = ['user','movie','star']
        verbose_name = "Рейтинг"
        verbose_name_plural = "Рейтинги"
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your problem text instead of linking an image from an external site.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation, Calling .save() will either create a new instance, or update an existing instance, depending on if an existing instance was passed when instantiating the serializer class:

```
# .save() will create a new instance.
serializer = CommentSerializer(data=data)

# .save() will update the existing `comment` instance.
serializer = CommentSerializer(comment, data=data)
```

In your case you are only passing new data and missing existing instance.

```
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = CreateRatingSerializer(data=request.data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found the problem and that was in the name of the function. I described this in below comment.

Answer (score 0):

I renamed  `def new(self,validated_data):` to `def create(self,validated_data):` in serializers.py and all started working. >.<